# open a modal windows in a server

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hi everyone I have a modal windows in joomla 3.0!

I pass the router to javascript like this

```
 <?php $link    =JURI::root().'index.php?option=com_projects&view=proyectos&format=raw&task=todosProyecto&id='. $item->id;?>

            <li class="item" data-id="id-<?php echo $item->id ?>" data-type="<?php echo $item->categoria ?>">
                <a href="#modal" id="<?php echo $link;?>" role="<?php echo $item->id ?>" class="picture" data-toggle="modal">
                    <img src="<?php echo JURI::root()?><?php echo $item->imagen_portada; ?>"/></a>
                <p class="titulo"><?php echo $item->nombre; ?></p>
                   <p> <?php echo $item->municipio; ?>(<?php echo $item->pais; ?>)<br><?php echo $item->year; ?>
                </p>
```

In local when I open the modal windows it work well, but in the server the modal windows show me the index.php view of this component.

I think that my problem is here, when I take the request for the model I have this.

```
   public function elegirSeleccionados(){
        $this->pagination = $this->get('pagination');
        $this->items = $this->get('recientes');
        $this->list = $this->get('list');
        parent::display();
    }
```

But $this->get('list'); is null so I have to asigned a null value to list.
I changed by that..

```
 $this->list =  $this->items;
```

but dont work to!

Any idea!!!

Comment: What is the value of `$link` on your server environment? I'd say it's different than on localhost

Comment: Hi @piotr_czno, it the same link.... But I think that found the problem, but not the solution...  I writte in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this code?

First part looks like a **Layout** (`views\proyectos\tmpl\default.php`) and the second one like a **View** (`views\proyectos\view.html.php`).

If it is so, I'd say you are not really loading items in View from the Model. Try using `$this->items = $this->get('Items');`

But this doesn't explain different results on server and local host.

Comment: Hi @piotr_czno thanks for help me, I explain better... I modified again the question!

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone I solved the problem... the name of my view hava a Camelcase for example itemId and joomla try to find itemid, so don´t find the view and show the default view in the modal.

So I change the name of file without camelCase and now work.!

Comment: This happens when you develop on Windows (case-insensitive file names) but deploy on Linux (case sensitive) where `Default.php` is a different file than `default.php`. Use lowercase filenames